# Why showmount receive local IP(get error timed out)?

Tags: networking, nat, nfs

I configured NFS over WAN(Internet) on VPS. VPS in Moscow, me near, The ping over Internet is about 5ms

And mount work well(both on two clients, with CentOS and Ubunutu)
But showmount doesn't work on Ubunutu. On Centos showmount work and because of this a can use easy mount with autofs comman `cd /net/ip/folder`

On ubuntu showmount doesn't work, it show `rpc mount export: RPC: Timed out`

And I noticed that in CentOS showmount in netstat output shows my VPS public ip section foreign ip
And on Ubuntu showmount in netstat output i see VPS local ip

```
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.19.79:48194     178.216.103.243:111     TIME_WAIT   -                   

tcp        0      1 192.168.19.79:49234     172.31.32.4:20048       SYN_SENT    4394/showmount  
tcp        0     32 192.168.19.84:60688     84.17.61.35:443         FIN_WAIT1   -
```

How to fix this?
I have already trying allow all incoming connection in ufw on Ubuntu clietn? but doesn't help me

Comment: showmount uses different port, which might be closed by firewall

Comment: @kofemann closed port not the problem. As I mentioned above, Centos work correctly, and in Ububntu showmoun doesn't work. Execatly over WAN

If I make VPN, to put all these VMs in local area, showmount work great in both client machines(Ubuntu and CentOS)